# "Getting something decreased" or "decrease something?"

Tags: passive-voice, future-tense

I'm trying to set a title like:

> Choosing between decrease your skills and Death

Is it correct to say:

> Choosing between getting your skills decreased and Death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we parse this title, it is going to read:

> Choosing between (X) and (Y)

We know Y is "death". What should X be? Since "death" is a noun, then X should also be a noun, or it should use the gerund form to make a phrase that functions as a noun. That's why your second suggested title is the better one:

> Choosing between (Getting Your Skills Decreased) and (Death)

There are other ways you could accomplish the same thing. For example, *decrease* can function as a verb or noun, so you could write the title like this:

> Choosing between (a Decrease in Skills) and (Death)

or, we could change Y, and make both X and Y verbs:

> Choosing between Decreasing your Skills and Dying

---

While there's no grammatical problem, I think a title beginning with "Choosing between Getting..." sounds just a little awkward, but there are two ways we might fix that. First, we can shuffle X and Y:

> Choosing between Death and Getting Your Skills Decreased

or, we could opt for this title, which moves the "choice" part to the end:

> Getting Your Skills Decreased or Death: Making the Choice

---

<sub>As for why I capitalized the way I did, there's more information about that at [this column](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/capitalstitle.htm).</sub>

Comment: Isn't `Decreasing your Skills` means: you are the one who decrease the skills ?

Comment: I'm assuming the context here is some kind of gaming? If so, in light of your question, maybe an even better title would be: **Decreased Skills or Death: Making the Choice**.

Answer (score 1):

Your second version is correct, except for two somewhat off-topic quibbles:

1. "Death" probably shouldn't be capitalized where it appears at the end of the title, or all other words should be capitalized as well, except "and," depending on how this title is to be used.
2. The space before the question mark is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think the question marks were meant to be part of the title, and I've edited the question accordingly. As for the space before (instead of after) punctuation, I'm not sure how that happens, but I end up making that correction a [lot](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/15427/revisions). It seems to be a common error for English learners.

Comment: I've noticed that too! All over the place (including other Stack Exchanges)! I wonder if teachers are somehow responsible, or if it's a characteristic of certain foreign languages...Might make a good meta-question!